# What is the best way to draw plots in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, graphics, qgraphicsview

I am using Qt to draw a spectrogram like this:

[image: spectrogram].
I also want to be able to select regions of the graph and edit them, as well as scrolling and zooming around.

I am considering `QGraphicsView` class but not sure about its performance. As I know, the objects in `QGraphicsView` are stored individually and drawing a huge amount of dots might impact performance.

What Qt classes should I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely do not use the `QGraphicsItem` for every dot/mark. Good approach would be to generate a `QPixmap` representing your spectrogram and than place this pixmap into the `QGraphicsScene` as a single item (`QGraphicsPixmapItem` can be used for that).

To draw on the `QPixmap` use the `QPainter`. Maybe a little example will be useful:

```
const int spectrWidth = 1000;
const int spectrHeight = 500;
QPixmap spectrPixmap(spectrWidth, spectrHeight);
QPainter p(&spectrPixmap);

for (int ir = 0; ir < spectrHeight; ir++)
{
    for (int ic = 0; ic < spectrWidth; ic++)
    {
        double data = getDataForCoordinates(ic, ir); // your function
        QColor color = getColorForData(data);  // your function
        p.setPen(color);
        p.drawPoint(ic, ir);
    }
}
```

The `getDataForCoordinates()` and `getColorForData()` are just example functions demonstrating how it could work. You have probably different way how to obtain data and it's color.

**EDIT**

But if you do not need a zoom/pan functionality than even easier would be just to paint directly on the `QWidget` in the `QWidget::paintEvent()` and not using the `QGraphicsView`/`QGraphicScene` at all.

Comment: Can I use `QImage` instead of `QPixmap`?

Comment: Yes, you can, but why? ...  `QPixmap` *is designed and optimized for showing images on screen.* ... (from Qt documentation)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use either [QCustomPlot](http://www.qcustomplot.com/) or [Qwt](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/) for this purpose.
Both have very good documentation.

If you choose to work with Qwt take a look at [QwtPlotSpectrogram Class](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/class_qwt_plot_spectrogram.html).

Answer (score 0):

QCustomPlot is external library, if you are looking for something native to QT then have a look at [QPainter class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html).